# Javascript array.length property

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working through the fabously-named learnyounode.  #9 is "JUGGLING ASYNC" and the instructions are to take in 3 urls as params and output the content in parameter order.  I got it working by including a counter, but my original did not work:

```
var http = require('http'),
  bl = require('bl'),
  store = [],
  count = 0; //added later

process.argv.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  if (index > 1) {
    http.get(element, function(response) {
      response.pipe(bl(function(err, data) {
        store[index] = data.toString();
        count++; //added later
        if (store.length == 3) {
            store.forEach(function(e,is,a) {
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
      }));
    });
  }
});
```

Now the thing works fine if you replace store.length with count on line 12, I just can't figure out why .length on the array wasn't enough.
Anyone know?

Comment: I acknowledge a for loop instead of process.argv.forEach would have saved 2 loops.

Comment: I cannot tell what your question is. What was your code originally, what did you expect, and what did you get instead?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking..

Comment: `store.length` can give odd responses; index should change consistently in the `forEach` loop.  Try index ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript arrays, when you give an empty array an item at index 5, it implies that the array is 6 items long, with items 0-4 being undefined.

For example

```
var x = [];
console.log(x.length); //prints 0;
x[2] = "hello, world";
console.log(x.length); //prints 3;
```

You're skipping the first two elements but still using `index`, so when you enter your first element into `store`, you're entering it into `store[2]`, making the length 3, when `count` is only 1.

Comment: Ah, this was a surprise to me... (but perhaps it shouldn't)
`var x=[];
x["a"]=1;
console.log(x.length); // prints 0`

Comment: Yeah javascript has a pretty loose interpretation of objects. I just used something in a loop the other day like `x[otherArray.indexOf(item)] = item`. If it can't find it in the other array it goes into -1, which doesn't count towards `length` so essentially gets ignored.

Comment: Playing around with it further, I started over with:
`var x=[];
x['a']='a';
console.log(x); // yields [ a: 'a' ]
console.log(x.length) // again, 0
x[1]=1;
console.log(x); // yields [ , 1, a: 'a' ]
console.log(x.length); // yields 2 for the empty 0 place and the 1 place`
...anyway, I though that was interesting.  It's almost like these alpha indexed array items are actually object items, and thus don't get counted.  That's probably a silly way of thinking of it...

Comment: The Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) has some really great documentation on javascript and HTML. It might help to read up on [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (there's also a specific section for the [relationship between length and numerical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Relationship_between_length_and_numerical_properties)). A `[]` is actually a simple object that is an instance of the Array class, [with many functions and properties](http://goo.gl/4bYjr).

Answer (score 0):

You should use your `count` variable, because:

When you you do `store[1] = data.toString();`, for example, you get an array `[undefined, 1]` with length = 2. And you want it to be 1.

Comment: No. The instructions are clear: output the results in *parameter order*.

Comment: If you `push` it to the end of the array, you'll have an indeterministic order.

Comment: @Bergi, it's an array, not an object. Arrays always keep the order. Regular objects - don't.

Comment: @Bergi, or could you please give me a link where I can read about it, if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I'm not saying the array is forgetting the order, I say that you are appending them in the possibly wrong order. Notice that `http.get` and `bl` are asynchronous.